# Is it good practice to create a background job within an init script if the process can not daemonize itself?

Tags: init-script, daemon

I am fairly new to *nix, and have come across the need to drop multiple processes, that should be run 100% of the time. to background using `&`.

I use the following line in an init.d script to do this (running as the user `user`:

`su -c 'process arg1 arg2 -w - | process2 arg1 -r - &' user`

(where -w writes to and -r reads from STDOUT, STDIN)

Specifically, I know this is not generally acceptable, as the processes aren't well shielded from outside influence.

Is it acceptable to create background jobs for "services?"

Should I instead use a FIFO/named pipe to handle the interprocess communication?

If so, should I still create both processes as background jobs?  Is this stable?

For specifics, please refer to [this mailing list thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.network.argus/8603).

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Just a quick hint, have a look at the various *process supervision* tools, e.g. daemontools, runit, upstart, systemd -- they all *require* non-self-daemonizing services.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that itself.  With the above "solution," I relied on the processes own ability to create PID files, then referred to them `if -f`with `killproc`.

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically, I know this is not generally acceptable, as the processes aren't well shielded from outside influence.
>
> Is it acceptable to create background jobs for "services?"

If there's no other way (that is, the service won't fork on its own), then probably yes. Debian's `start-stop-daemon` has a `--background` parameter for such cases:

```
   -b, --background
          Typically used with programs that don't  detach  on  their  own.
          This option will force start-stop-daemon to fork before starting
          the  process,  and  force  it  into  the  background.   WARNING:
          start-stop-daemon  cannot  check  the exit status if the process
          fails to execute for any reason. This is a last resort,  and  is
          only  meant  for  programs  that either make no sense forking on
          their own, or where it's not feasible to add the code  for  them
          to do this themselves.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first question is already answered, I'll concentrate on the last both.

Some days ago I struggled about a similar problem: I had to start some processes via pipe from `/etc/init.d` scripts.  To solve this, I had a look at RHEL6 (`daemon` and `killproc` of `/etc/init.d/functions`) and Debian (`start-stop-daemon`).  What I learned was, that both did not handle pipes (very well).  Even it was somehow possible to start them, there were major problems stopping them.  Therefore I wrote a small tool [`pipexec`](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec).  This program starts a pipe of programs but behaves like one program.  Example: when a `SIGTERM` is send to `pipexec` it kills all the children and afterwards itself.  Also pid file handling is supported - which gives you an easy live when integrating with RHEL6 `daemon` and `killproc`.

> Should I instead use a FIFO/named pipe to handle the interprocess communication?
>   If so, should I still create both processes as background jobs? Is this stable?

I also thought about this - but for me this is to complicated and I did not have really good experience when it comes to fifos regarding stability and reliability (maybe this is my problem - but therefore I rarely use them ;-) )

I integrated `pipexec` with RHEL6 and there are no problems; it just runs.

Kind regards - Andreas